# Build and render infinite hierarchical category tree from self-referential category table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, hierarchical-trees

I have a `Categories` table in which each category has a `ParentId` that can refer to any other category's `CategoryId` that I want to display as multi-level HTML list, like so:

```
<ul class="tree">
    <li>Parent Category
        <ul>
            <li>1st Child Category
                <!-- more sub-categories -->
            </li>
            <li>2nd Child Category
                <!-- more sub-categories -->
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Presently I am recursively rendering a partial view and passing down the next category. It works great, but it's wrong because I'm executing queries in a view.

How can I render the list into a tree object and cache it for quick display every time I need a list of all hierarchical categories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a view model class that is self referential.

Populate it in the appropriate model class (or perhaps in your `DataContext` partial class) using the query you are executing in the view.

Wrap the method that does the query in a method that checks and stores the result in `Cache`.

Make sure you invalidate the cache whenever changes are made to the category tree.

If the query executes a lot of queries (one per tree level), then consider getting the contents of the category table as a flat list and then using linq to objects to project it into your view model class.